# Refugee from SPSS having issues with fit.contrast in R

Tags: r, anova, contrasts

I'm trying to wean myself off of SPSS and switch to R for psych statistics and I'm mostly getting there, but I've run into a real roadblock with `fit.contrast` from the [gmodels](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmodels/index.html) package. As far as I can tell, even the provided example doesn't work properly--either that, or I grossly misunderstand contrasts in R (always a possibility).

First let's look at the example code that comes with the documentation for `gmodels::fit.contrast()`:

```
set.seed(03215)
Genotype <- sample(c("WT","KO"), 1000, replace=TRUE)
Time <- factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace=TRUE))
y <- rnorm(1000)
data <- data.frame(y, Genotype, Time)

model <- aov( y ~ Genotype + Time + Genotype:Time, data=data )
model.tables(model, "means")

fit.contrast( model, "Genotype", rbind("KO vs WT"=c(-1,1) ), conf=0.95 , df=T)
```

For me, this produces the following output:

```
                   Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)   lower CI  upper CI
GenotypeKO vs WT 0.01683876  0.1095764 0.1536714   0.8779 -0.1981888 0.2318664
```

Now consider the later example code:

```
model <- aov( y ~ Genotype + Time + Genotype:Time, data=data,
              contrasts=list(Genotype=make.contrasts(cm.G),
                             Time=make.contrasts(cm.T) )
)

summary(model, split=list( Genotype=list( "KO vs WT"=1 ),
                           Time = list( "1 vs 2" = 1,
                                        "2 vs 3" = 2 ) ) )
```

This produces this output for me:

```
                                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Genotype                           1    1.2  1.1687   1.121  0.290
  Genotype: KO vs WT               1    1.2  1.1687   1.121  0.290
Time                               2    0.7  0.3677   0.353  0.703
  Time: 1 vs 2                     1    0.2  0.1784   0.171  0.679
  Time: 2 vs 3                     1    0.6  0.5571   0.534  0.465
Genotype:Time                      2    1.2  0.5760   0.552  0.576
  Genotype:Time: KO vs WT.1 vs 2   1    0.3  0.3265   0.313  0.576
  Genotype:Time: KO vs WT.2 vs 3   1    0.8  0.8256   0.792  0.374
Residuals                        994 1036.6  1.0429
```

I'm completely flummoxed here. The p-values for the two tests on Genotype should match, but they don't! 
The p-values are not the same and the F-value isn't the square of the t-value. Also, the value computed
for the contrast estimate (0.0168) is NOT the difference in the two means... why not?

Any help in understanding what fit.contrast is doing here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you specified codes of -1 and +1, we would not expect the coefficient to represent the difference between the group means. You have placed the groups 2 units apart on the contrast, so we should expect the coefficient to represent *half* of the group mean difference. And in this case, half of the group mean difference when Time = 0, considering the interaction.

Comment: OK, but why do the significance tests disagree?

Answer (score 4):

My initial remark is: why do you need these functions from the `gmodels` package to accomplish this? These are basic tasks that can be accomplished straightforwardly in base R, which is what I would recommend.

But to answer your question directly, the issue here is that `fit.contrast` is using "type 3" tests of effects while `summary` is using "type 2" tests. This can be verified most easily using `Anova` from the `car` package, which lets you select the type of sums of squares that you desire:

```
library(car)

> Anova(model, type=2)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: y
Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
Genotype         1.09   1  1.0495 0.3059
Time             0.74   2  0.3526 0.7029
Genotype:Time    1.15   2  0.5524 0.5758
Residuals     1036.64 994       

> Anova(model, type=3)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: y
Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
(Intercept)      0.10   1  0.0935 0.7599
Genotype         0.02   1  0.0236 0.8779
Time             1.87   2  0.8954 0.4088
Genotype:Time    1.15   2  0.5524 0.5758
Residuals     1036.64 994
```

A description of the difference between these two methods can be found here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-August/111854.html

Comment: Ahh, right, I didn't see the unbalanced nature of the design. That makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommended to not use reserved words as `R` objects names. For genotype contrast it is clear that the p-values from ANOVA and contrast statement from gmodels are identical and F=t^2.

```
library(gmodels)
set.seed(03215)
Genotype <- sample(c("WT","KO"), 1000, replace=TRUE)
Time <- factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace=TRUE))
y <- rnorm(1000)
dat <- data.frame(y, Genotype, Time)

fit1 <- aov( y ~ Genotype + Time + Genotype:Time, data=dat)
summary(fit1)


              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Genotype        1    1.2  1.1687   1.121  0.290
Time            2    0.7  0.3677   0.353  0.703
Genotype:Time   2    1.2  0.5760   0.552  0.576
Residuals     994 1036.6  1.0429

model.tables(fit1, "means")
Tables of means
Grand mean

0.01447773 

 Genotype 
           KO        WT
     -0.02154   0.04693
rep 474.00000 526.00000

 Time 
            1         2         3
      0.03267   0.03313  -0.02539
rep 350.00000 334.00000 316.00000

 Genotype:Time 
        Time
Genotype 1      2      3     
     KO    0.02   0.02  -0.11
     rep 160.00 155.00 159.00
     WT    0.04   0.04   0.06
     rep 190.00 179.00 157.00
```

As (-1)*(-0.02154)+(1)*(0.04693) = 0.06847

```
fit.contrast(fit1, "Genotype", rbind("KO vs WT"=c(1, -1)), conf=0.95, df=TRUE)

                  Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)  DF   lower CI upper CI
GenotypeKO vs WT 0.06869178 0.06477589 1.060453 0.2891962 994 -0.0584214 0.195805
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand at all. When I run your exact code, I get the same result I originally got, not the answer you posted: